# How to prove/disprove $H=\{(1),(123),(132)\}$ is normal in $G=A_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

I can't figure out how to do this without manually computing all of the possibilities. Here are some relevant theorems I know:

$H$ is normal in $G$ iff:

1. $\quad\forall g\in G, gHg^{-1}=H$
2. $\quad\forall g\in G, gH=Hg$
3. $\quad\forall g\in G, gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$

Comment: Isn't $H$ just the trivial group, $\{(1)\}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $A_5$?

Comment: Of course, $A_5$ is a simple group, so it has no nontrivial normal subgroups. But you should actually compute precisely the element(s) of $H$.

Comment: @Jonathaniui $A_5$ is meant to mean the alternating group of degree 5.

Comment: Oops, it occurred to me I forgot a comma in defining the elements of $H$. See the new title for the edit. My mistake.

Comment: $H$ is not normal in $A_5$ (it's simple!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a tip, maybe you can construct an homeomorphism that has $H$ as its kernel and then H must be normal in $A_5$ because you know (or can easily proof) the kernel is always a normal subgroup of the domain.

Edit: Way to disprove it.

Disprove is easy, take an element in $A_5$ for example $(12345)$ now, for H to be normal $(12345)(1)(12345)=(12345)(12345)=(13524)$ should be in $H$ (because $(1)\in H$) but is obvious that $(13524)\notin H$ and then $H$ is not normal in $A_5$.

Comment: Not a constructive tip in this case.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't learned what homeomorphisms or kernels are yet :)

Comment: This is the standard way though, in general using one of the three conditions OP gave is difficult.

Comment: @user3724404 Are you sure the proposition ask you to prove $H$ is indeed normal in there? Because $A_5$ is a simple group and it has no proper non trivial normal subgroup, so there is no demonstration because it is false.

Comment: @Jonathaniui Oops again, I had forgotten that the instructions were to prove OR DISPROVE a few hypotheses. No wonder I'd been struggling on this. Title edited again.

Comment: @user3724404 Disprove is easy, take an element in $A_5$ for example $(12345)$ now, check that $(12345)(1)(12345) \notin H$ this is because you have that $(1)\in H$ so for H to be normal  $(12345)(1)(12345)$ should be in H.